# Observing data that saved with childByAutoId

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `childByAutoId` to save each message in Firebase.

now when observing data, I want each query to get 10 older messages using `.queryStarting(atValue: )` `.queryEnding(atValue: )`

Is it possible with `childByAutoId`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. But that's not generally best practice - don't query by the key. Query by a child in the node.

```
messages
  -Y8hji98jasdjkas
    datestamp: "20170405"
  -Yin99s9ks9kksok
    datestamp: "20170407"
  -Y7iijs9jsk9999j
    datestamp: "20170409"

queryOrdered(byChild: "datestamp").queryStarting(atValue: "20170405")
                                  .queryEnding(atValue: "20170408")
```

will retrive these two older child nodes

```
  -Y8hji98jasdjkas
    datestamp: "20170405"
  -Yin99s9ks9kksok
    datestamp: "20170407"
```

Comment: Nice answer! But did you mean `func queryOrdered(byChild key: String)`?

Comment: @PauloMattos Good catch. Thanks. Nothing like writing code without testing it. lol.